# Issue with jquery startwith selector

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I am trying to run the jquery with no success:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
     var pathname = window.location.pathname;
     var a = pathname.split('/');
     if (a[1]^ = "login" || a[1] == "") {
         $("#product").css("margin-left", "0px");
     } elseif (a[1] == "admin.aspx") {
         $(".pnlBreadcrumb").css("margin-left", "10px");
     }
});
</script>
```

Can any one assist me , where I am getting it wrong

Thanks

Comment: yep everything is there , checked

Comment: What is this `a[1]^ = "login"` supposed to do?

Comment: check if the path starts with login then modify css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` is a bitwise xor-operator.

- Use the [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method, which returns the position of the found string.
- Use `else if` instead of `elseif`.

Note: You do not have to split the `location.pathname` property at `/`, since the path will always start with `/`. Simply include the slash in the code.

Code:

```
$(function() {
    var pathname = location.pathname;

    if (pathname.indexOf('/login') === 0 || pathname === '/') {
        $("#product").css("margin-left", "0");
    } else if (pathname === "/admin.aspx") {
        $(".pnlBreadcrumb").css("margin-left", "10px");
    }
});
```

PS. This issue is caused by a bad understanding of JavaScript. I strongly recommend to learn JavaScript before using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

The start-with selector only works **in jQuery selectors**

Here you're trying to use it on a **plain string**:

```
if (a[1]^ = "login" ... )
```

Try:

```
 if (a[1].indexOf('login') === 0 ... )
```